# C# Datagridview Column Name in Switch

Tags: c#, datagridview, switch-statement

I am trying to validate my cells pending on what cell they are in when the dataerror fires for my datagridview.

Here is my code:

```
private void dataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
  if (_licDataSet.LicenseFileTable.Rows(e.RowIndex).Columns(e.ColumnIndex) == "test")

    switch (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name)
    {
      case "AllowAsRemoteDesktopColumn" :
        // do not think there are any checks for this column
        // we'll find out shortly though!
        break;
      case dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name : 
        // ^^^ this errors with "A constant value is expected"
        // do something
        break;
    }
}
```

I am erroring at the ^^^ position as you can see from the message.

What am I doing wrong? I would think that the owningcolumn name was constant at this point...?

Help!

*** *EDIT* ***
*How do I get the column name of the current cell is my question if the above doesn't work?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an enum of my expected value and referencing them. It was the only way I could guarantee if the changed that I'd get a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a constant representing one of the values the CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name *could* be.  Something like "anothervalue", and not a property of an object.

Answer (score 0):

In c# switch statement's cases can only be 'const' literals , strings and enums. It cannot be property or field of class.
msdn link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I understand the switch part, the part I don't get is how I get the name of the column of the current cell without hard coding the name in...

Comment: That is what you do:

    if(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name == 
       dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name)
    {
      // do something
    }

Comment: That will always come out to be true. That's like saying if a = a do something... a always equals itself...

Answer (score 0):

You are using as a case statement the same property as in a switch check. Probably you need to replace second case with `default` keyword.